# Magento2 Add custom tracking script when product is added to cart

Tags: magento2

Magento2 I need to add custom tracking script when product is added to cart. This script is to be added only once with product data of that particular product that is added to cart.

I have 2 scenarios as my site is multi website, in 1 product after being added to cart user is redirected to Cart page & in 2nd Ajax add to cart.

How can I achieve this?